# Deleting SQL Rows and DataGrid Rows in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datagridview

Me again :)

I am trying to Delete rows from a DataGridView and delete the same value from SQL Database as well at the same time.

Here is what I have so far, which is something I just picked up on Google:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\INFLOWSQL;Initial Catalog=RioDiary;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    mycommand.Connection = myconnect
    myconnect.Open()
    mycommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM MyDiary" + DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value + "'"


    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        mycommand.Parameters(1).Value = row.Cells(0).Value
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
    Next row
    myconnect.Close()

End Sub
```

It obviously doesn't work. The error I get is:

```
Invalid index 1 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=0.
```

Hope someone can shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means, you tried to access parameter in index 1 (index 1 means 2nd parameter. Zero-based index) when you don't have any parameter added to `mycommand` yet.

Assuming that the first cell in `DataGridViewRow` contains the id for use in SQL parameter, you can try something like this :

```
.......
mycommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM MyDiary WHERE Id = @Id"

'add parameter once
mycommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.VarChar)

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    'set parameter value to Id column of current row
    mycommand.Parameters(0).Value = row.Cells(0).Value
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
Next row
.......
```

Comment: You beauty!! Thanks again mate.